# How can I dynamically change the XML structure of a string in SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I need a SQL script that will to pull an XML string from the DB [varchar(max)], inspect it, and update it *if* it fits a specific situation.

Imagine that my xml is in the following format:

```
<root>
  <level1>
    <level2>
      <level3 />
      <level3 />
    </level2>
  </level1>
  <level1>
    <level2>
      <level3>
        <level4>
          <level5>
            <level6 here="now is the time for XYZ">
              <options>
                <option this="that" />
                <option me="you" />
              </options>
            </level6>
          </level5>
        </level4>
      </level3>
    </level2>
  </level1>
  <level1>
    <level2>
      <level3>
        <level4>
          <level5>
            <level6 here="this one is not of interest">
              <options>
                <option this="that" />
                <option me="you" />
              </options>
            </level6>
          </level5>
        </level4>
      </level3>
    </level2>
  </level1>
  <level1>
    <level2>
      <level3>
        <level4>
          <level5>
            <level6 here="now is the time for ABC">
              <options>
                <option this="that" />
                <option me="you" />
                <option here="now" />
              </options>
            </level6>
          </level5>
        </level4>
      </level3>
    </level2>
  </level1>
</root>
```

So, what I want to do is to update all elements whose name is "level6" and which have an attribute called "here" whose value **begins** with "now is the time".  So, that should match just two elements above.

But, that's not the only selection criteria.  The list of options must not contain `<option here="now" />`.  So, that should leave us with just one element to update.

```
<level6 here="now is the time for XYZ">
    <options>
        <option this="that" />
        <option me="you" />
    </options>
 </level6>
```

To that element, I then want to add the missing `<option here="now" />`, so that becomes:

```
<level6 here="now is the time for XYZ">
    <options>
        <option this="that" />
        <option me="you" />
        <option here="now" />
    </options>
 </level6>
```

So, the end result should be:

```
 <root>
  <level1>
    <level2>
      <level3 />
      <level3 />
    </level2>
  </level1>
  <level1>
    <level2>
      <level3>
        <level4>
          <level5>
            <level6 here="now is the time for XYZ">
              <options>
                <option this="that" />
                <option me="you" />
                <option here="now" />      // <- this one new
              </options>
            </level6>
          </level5>
        </level4>
      </level3>
    </level2>
  </level1>
  <level1>
    <level2>
      <level3>
        <level4>
          <level5>
            <level6 here="this one is not of interest">
              <options>
                <option this="that" />
                <option me="you" />
              </options>
            </level6>
          </level5>
        </level4>
      </level3>
    </level2>
  </level1>
  <level1>
    <level2>
      <level3>
        <level4>
          <level5>
            <level6 here="now is the time for ABC">
              <options>
                <option this="that" />
                <option me="you" />
                <option here="now" />
              </options>
            </level6>
          </level5>
        </level4>
      </level3>
    </level2>
  </level1>
</root>
```

Assume that I can read the data out of the DB into a string, and that I know how to update the DB, so it's really how to manipulate the xml string in SQL (SQL Server).

Comment: What have you tried? :)

Answer (score 1):

**You can use XML DML (data modification) with the `.modify` function to change the XML.**

```sql
SET @xml.modify('
  insert <option here="now" />
  as last into
  ( /root/level1/level2/level3/level4/level5/level6
     [substring(@here, 1, 15) = "now is the time"]
     /options [not(/option[@here = "now"])]
   )[1]');
```

This works as follows:

- `insert <option here="now" />` this is the value we are inserting
- `as last into` it goes after other child nodes of the selected one
- `/root/level1/level2/level3/level4/level5/level6` this gets us that `level6` node
- `[substring(@here, 1, 15) = "now is the time"]` predicates the node to have a `here` attribute starting with that value. You must modify the length parameter to match the value you are comparing. There is no `LIKE` in XQuery
- `/options [not(/option[@here = "now"])]` we look for an `options` node which has *no* `option` child which in turn has a `here="now"` attribute
- `[1]` the first such node

If you need to modify multiple nodes within a single XML document, you need to run this in loop

```sql
DECLARE @i int = 20; --max nodes

WHILE @xml.exist('
  /root/level1/level2/level3/level4/level5/level6
     [substring(@here, 1, 15) = "now is the time"]
     /options [not(option[@here = "now"])]
   ') = 1
BEGIN

    SET @xml.modify('
      insert <option here="now" /> as last into
      ( /root/level1/level2/level3/level4/level5/level6
         [substring(@here, 1, 15) = "now is the time"]
         /options [not(option[@here = "now"])]
       )[1]');
     
    SET @i -= 1;
    IF @i = 0
        BREAK;
END;
```

You can also do this for a whole table

```sql
DECLARE @i int = 20; --max nodes

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE XmlColumn.exist('
      /root/level1/level2/level3/level4/level5/level6
         [substring(@here, 1, 15) = "now is the time"]
         /options [not(option[@here = "now"])]
       ') = 1)
BEGIN

    UPDATE t
    SET XmlColumn.modify('
      insert <option here="now" /> as last into
      ( /root/level1/level2/level3/level4/level5/level6
         [substring(@here, 1, 15) = "now is the time"]
         /options [not(option[@here = "now"])]
       )[1]')
    FROM YourTable t
    WHERE XmlColumn.exist('
      /root/level1/level2/level3/level4/level5/level6
         [substring(@here, 1, 15) = "now is the time"]
         /options [not(option[@here = "now"])]
       ') = 1;
     
    SET @i -= 1;
    IF @i = 0
        BREAK;
END;
```

For very large datasets it may be faster to rebuild the whole XML using XQuery, with the extra node added using Constructed XML.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=462057322596d742ef015084f2c2788f)